# Is there a way to write data attributes in zen coding?

Tags: emmet

I use data attributes more every day, and I really miss a simple way to add a data attribute while using zen coding. I mean I can add inline style (not that I ever use it)

```
div[style=color:red;]
```

why can't I add data attribute like

```
div[data-color=pink]
```

Any work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can:

```
div[data-color='pink']
```

Comment: Not that i'm a big fan of the way they solve data attributes, but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `div[data-color=pink]` and it works.

Both `div[data-color="pink"]` and `div[data-color='pink']` don't.